# Can you dum-dum bullets using a knife?

Tags: weapons

In many Hollywood movies and other media such as comic books you can see someone pull out a knife and carve an X into the end of their bullets to turn make them like [dum-dum bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanding_bullet)s.

Is this possible in reality with a knife and will it have the intended effect that regular dum-dum bullets have of inflicting more sever pain? Or is this just something made up?

Comment: This is one of the best questions to be send to mythbusters. It has everything that a good episode needs.

Comment: It is most definitely possible to carve an "X" shaped mark into many kinds of unfired rounds (The amount of force it will require will vary, though. It might require a metal file to make a significant mark on a full-metal-jacket bullet). What effect it will have on impact remains to be seen. I *think* I remember a site that tested this at some point. Met me see if I can find it.

Comment: Somebody tried it on the "shooting range": http://www.theboxotruth.com/docs/bot32.htm not really scientific, but a start.

Comment: @cularis - Aaargh. You commented while I was writing my answer. Dammit, Beat.

Comment: @Fake Name, You wrote your answer while I was commenting! :D Looking at the time stamp, your answer was actually 2 minutes faster than my comment.

Comment: For those of us who apparently watch the wrong movies and read the wrong comics, can anyone cite some examples of the claim?

Answer (score 13):

The rather entertaining ["Box O' Truth" website](http://www.theboxotruth.com) did a [pretty thorough test of this.](http://www.theboxotruth.com/docs/bot32.htm)

Their conclusion:

> Lessons learned:
>
> 1. Cutting "x"s in bullets is harder than you might imagine.
> 2. It might make them slightly more effective than Ball, but not
>    nearly as effective as modern Jacketed Hollow Points.
> 3. The .45 ACP did not expand at all. This is probably the result of
>    a much thicker jacket than the 9mm.
> 4. The lead .38 Special shed its petals, but didn't expand at all.
> 5. Cutting the end off a **rifle** Ball cartridge will definitely make the
>    bullet expand or break up. Would this make it more lethal? Probably.
>    But not as much as a modern JSP (Jacketed Soft Point) bullet.
> 6. Reversing a [**rifle**] Ball bullet will cause it to expand and break up. Old
>    Elmer said that it killed game just fine. But Elmer didn't have access
>    to modern JSP ammo. If he had, I'm sure he would have preferred it.

I added the bold (and the second rifle note), as it's a critical distinction (rifle vs handgun). The only times I have seen this in hollywood is on handgun ammunition, which behaves very different from rifle ammunition.

It's not bulletproof (ha ha), but it is informative.

Comment: One can assume it really depends on the alloy of lead the bullet is made of, what the results will be, does water represent human flesh accurately? interesting site, +1